# Mail shows an inbox email with a light blue background

Tags: mail.app

In Apple Mail, normally inbox items have a white background, except for the selected items which have a dark blue background. Yet, yesterday I received an email from Apple which displays with a *light blue* background (third item on the picture).

**How to un-blue this Apple email?**

[image]

---

- macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
- Mail 11.3 (3445.6.18)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Menu Bar go to Mail>Preferences>Rules and unselect News from Apple.

You can read more about rules here : https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/use-rules-to-manage-your-inbox-mlhlp1017/mac and about highlighting here : https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/color-code-messages-mlhlp1063/mac

Answer (score 1):

Josh answer will solve the background coloring for newly received emails, by disabling a default Rule.

If you need/want to remove the background color for previously received emails:

1. Open Format -> Show Colors (or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>).
2. Choose the white color.
3. Select the emails for which you want to reset their color.
4. Right-click on those emails and choose *Apply rules*.
5. Close the color picker (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>).

(see: https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/color-code-messages-mlhlp1063/mac)